# how to control the flow of signals in signal slot mechanism?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am trying to make a neural network using signal and slot mechanism.
my neural network is not layered so I have a block of hidden neurons that are connected randomly. so I probably have loops in the structure which i like to have them.
 the question is when I start to emit signals from my input neurons, the first input neuron sends the signal to first hidden neuron and then i would rather want my program send the second signal to the second hidden neuron. but instead the first hidden neuron which has received its signal starts to emit its own signals and so on. when the first path reaches to the end (output neuron) then first input neuron emits the second signal to its second hidden neuron. this causes a problem which information flow partially. i.e. before a certain neuron recieves all its inputs it sends a signal only based on one input that it recieved. I tried to solve it by adding a counter that let the signal be emitted after all expected signals are recieved which in the case of the loops that I have in the structure it doesn't work. two neurons are waiting for the other one to send its signal then they have the full set of signals.
even i tried to let an empty signal ( valued 0 ) to be passed before all the signals are recieved and have the complete signal be passed after all signals are recieved. this one doesn't work since empty signals are accumulating the counter and it goes out of control.

```
void Neuron::receiveOutput(const int &senderIndex, const double &senderOutput)
{
this->m_sumOfSignals += m_indexedWeights[senderIndex] * senderOutput;
m_receivedSignals.push_back(senderIndex);

qDebug() << "I am neuron " << this->index() << " and I received a signal from neuron "
         << senderIndex << " valued " << senderOutput;
if(m_receivedSignals.size() == m_indexedWeights.size())
{
    m_output = this->activate();
    qDebug() << "I have receieved all " << m_receivedSignals.size() << " signals so I send my output as "
             << m_output;
    m_sumOfSignals = 0.0;
    emit sendOutput(m_index, m_output);
}

if(m_receivedSignals.size() < m_indexedWeights.size())
{
    m_output = this->activate();
    qDebug() << "so far I have receieved " << m_receivedSignals.size() << " signals so I send my output as "
             << m_output;
    emit sendOutput(m_index, 0.0);
}

if(m_receivedSignals.size() > m_indexedWeights.size())
{
    qDebug() << "I have receieved " << m_receivedSignals.size() << " signals so I stoped sending signals";
    return;
}
}
```

so my question is how can I control the signals flowing in the network?

Comment: Have you considered using delays instead of counting expected signals ?

Comment: how does delay would help me, I dont get it? can you explain more?

Comment: Just an idea: in a neuron, instead of counting signals, wait for a while before emitting yours.

Comment: I kinda fixed it for now by having a threshold, but still I need to know how to control the flow of signals.